# Necessary conditions for solving equations including addition of multiple absolute value functions

Tags: matrix-equations, absolute-value, absolute-convergence

I am in a trouble with finding a necessary condition of have only one unique solution a equation:
$$x -a= -\sum_{i}^{n}k_{i}\lvert b_{i}x-c_{i}\rvert$$
where $k_{i}\in(0,1)$. $$\\$$
I have tried Matlab simulation for some few values, and it looks a messy because the right hand side will be bent too many times. It seems that if we have:
$$\sum_{i}^{n}\lvert k_{i}b_{i}\rvert<1$$
and the put the max point of the right hand side to the right of the $f(x)=x-a$, then it will give only one solution to the question but I am not quite sure. Also I want some serious mathematical proof$$\\$$
Does anyone have any idea about this? $$\\$$
Thanks for your help.

Comment: Yes. If all the $k_i$ are positive, then for large $|x|$ the rhs will be roughly $B|x|$ where $B=-|\sum k_ib_i|$ is negative. So if $|B|>1$, then the equation will have no solutions or two solutions for most $a$. If you take $|B|<1$, then it should have a unique solution for all sufficiently large $a$. But on its own the condtion $|B|<1$ is neither necessary nor sufficient. It looks messy. Why do you want the answer? Are you just curious?

Comment: Hi Almagest, thanks for you comments. I am doing some other proofs and it somehow leads to utilize the solution status of the mentioned equation and then I can use iteration to solve the equation(requires proof of convergence). Here I am only worried about a particular point where $B>1$ but only a single point hit $x-a$ then the iteration will not converge but it still have only one solution.

Comment: where the iteration uses $x_{k+1}=a-\sum k_{i}|b_{i}x_{k}-c_{i}|$ and the Cauchy‘'s convergence requires that only when $B<1$ it converges